# Failed to start Light Display Manager?

Tags: boot

I'm new to Linux and installed the newest elementary OS.
Then I installed some packages and I was told to restart my computer. But when I booted it up again, it stuck at the logo.
Then I pressed Windows+Tab, I guess, and this screen appeared.
What am I supposed to do?
Please help me guys.

Here is the picture: https://ibb.co/jsDe3F

Comment: What does `systemctl status lightdm.service` say?

Comment: How can I type this in on the black screen?

Comment: you can go into recovery mode, on the grub menu select first 'advanced options for Elemetnary os', then the kernel on top which has (recovery mode) following the name. After the menu appears you can select the root shell below and execute the command listed above.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you can boot into `recovery mode` (selecteable in grub menu).
This will launch the system in text-only mode.
Try to login.
Once loged in, reinstall the lightdm packages with:

`sudo apt-get purge lightdm` (this will remove it)

`sudo apt-get autoremove` (this will autoremove leftovers)

`sudo apt-get install lightdm` (this will install it again)

Reboot, cross your fingers and hope you will se your default login screen again.

I have the same problem with my Elementary, but I cannot login to recovery mode and have to find another way to reinstall the lightdm.

Comment: There is no login into recovery mode but if he/she do not enable network before purging lightdm following your instructions will lead to a system without display manager!